# android parsing json

Tags: android, json, parsing

In android , we can parse json in 2 way

```
 1. using Json  ( android Api)
 2. using gson (External library)
```

when we should use JSON and when GSON.

Comment: Why to use third-party library/API if there is already native library exists?

Comment: to make parsing much more easier :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know GSON is a helper library that can be used to parse JSON. but since android SDK already supports JSON you , android API can be used directly and application won't be dependent on Third Party Library.

Comment: but in some cases GSON parsing is better than JSON API parsing while in some cases reverse is true.so what are the situations in which GSON is better than JSON API parsing.